# What comes first - Command or EventHandler?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, event-handling, icommand

In context of *Microsoft's MVVM pattern* and its Commanding/Event Handling aspects consider I am doing both binding a Command to a Control (say a Button) and subscribing to the control's Click event.

Is there any general rule what action takes place first - the processing of the code associated with the command or the one associated with the corresponding event handler?

Comment: I guess the biggest question, is why you would do both.  The key thing about making use of commands is that you would normally bind this to an ICommand in a ViewModel, and by doing this, the VM does not need to know anything about the Button.  Is this a case of mixing some code behind and a VM?  If you are using a VM, how are you binding to the buttons event?

Comment: @SteveSolomon Well I am trying to deal with the dynamical creation of controls during runtime. And in order to respect the MVVM pattern I try to leave all the necessary code in the VIEW. So I am currently using command binding for the connection between VIEW/VIEWMODEL and the EventHandlers for 'Inter-VIEW' manipulation.

Comment: I don't think it's specific.  I *think* off hand the first one to subscribe to the event would be raised first.  If the command is hooked up in the XAML, I expect that would subscribe first.  But, there's more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: If it isn't documented, the behavior may change in the future.  I'd suggest programming like it may change from call to call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EventHandlers are triggered before the bound ICommand.

Comment: This is correct. I've occasionally done both before when I want some view-specific check to occur prior to processing the command. If the check fails, the event can cancel the command.